# WTForms DateField returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a DateField that is part of a WTForm in Flask

```py
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField

dob = DateField('Date of Birth', [InputRequired()], format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

```py
    if form.is_submitted():
        print(form.dob.data)
```

HTML Template

```html
{{ form.dob.label }}
<input type="date" id="DateofBirth" name="dob" class="form-control">
```

When the form is submitted it returns `None`. All other fields of the form work properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it after a bit. Figured out I needed to remove the `format` parameter in the DateField object. The corrected field looks like this:

```py
dob = DateField([InputRequired()])
```

When submitted the `form.dob.data` now outputs the correct date. This answer on another semi-unrelated question helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/16549743. I guess HTML5 can't accept different formats as explained in that answer and passing the format parameter was messing things up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, the issue here, if this is the case, there is no way to set the format then? Isn't it?